# How to conjugate "their resting place(s)" in Kel Malei Rachamim?

Tags: tefilla, grammar-dikduk, torah-service, mourning-aveilus

The memorial prayer Kel Malei Rachamim concludes "may they rest in peace in their resting place[s], and let us say Amen."

Okay, how to say "resting place[s]." *Mishkavam? Mishkaveihem? Mishkevoseihem?* Seems I hear people unsure on this one.

Comment: I've always heard משכבותם

Comment: For all male groups? All female? Mixed?

Comment: In my shul, they only say kel maleh for one person at a time.  Maybe the difficulty of conjugating is the reason? (/tongue-in-cheek)

Answer (score 1):

The Artscroll Siddur has משכבותיהם for a group of men and משכבותיהן for a group of women.